# MVC model required field sometimes is null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

*Update:* We told users to register on a co-worker's computer and, so far, that is fixing the problem. We had expected the problem to be in their combination of data so we examined the database. Since it worked on another computer that, supposedly, had the same configuration, we are stumped again. These computers are tightly controlled by their IT Departments and should have the exact same restrictions because the users have the same roles. Does anybody have any idea which user-configurable setting in IE 9 or 11 could cause this problem?

*Original Text:*
Our ASP MVC 5 model has several required fields but two have a problem. For 3% of users, the values of these fields are NULL in the posts for the AJAX calls and the submit post.

The user's selection from the **Service** dropdown makes an AJAX call with the ID of the **Service** selection to populate the **Region** dropdown. For hundreds of users, the IIS logs and database tracing show the call goes through with the correct parameter. They see the correctly filtered list. However, for a few users, the parameter is null and the call returns an unfiltered list of all regions. We see the null parameter in the DB tracing.

The user's selection from the **Region** dropdown makes an AJAX call with the IDs of the **Service** and **Region** selection to populate the **Location** dropdown. For hundreds of users, the IIS logs and database tracing show the call goes through with the correct parameter. They see the correctly filtered list. However, for a few users, the parameter is null and the call returns an unfiltered list of all **Locations**. We see the null parameter in the DB tracing.

The few users with the problem scroll through the dropdowns to pick the valid combination of **Role**, **Service**, **Region**, and **Location**. Then they click "submit" and, once again, the **Service** and **Region** selections are missing from the values in the post. Those two selections are NULL so the [Required] attribute on the model keeps the user on the same page with a nagging message to "Enter a Service" and "Enter a Region." For these few users, Region and Service are always null for AJAX posts or the submission post. The other fields are fine.

All users are on IE11. Other users in the same office do not have the problem. The jQuery library is downloaded from our site, no third party download.

Here is relevant code from the Index.cshtml

```
<div class="RegistrationFieldLine">
    <label for="rolesid" class="RegistrationFieldLabel">User Type*</label>
    <span class="RegistrationFieldBox">
        @Html.DropDownList("Roles", ViewData["RoleId"] as SelectList, "SELECT ROLE TYPE ------------------------", new { id = "rolesid", @class = "RegistrationFieldBox" })
    </span>
    <span class="RegistrationFieldError">@Html.ValidationMessage("Roles")</span>
</div>

<div id="servicetxt" class="RegistrationFieldLine">
    <label for="serviceid" class="RegistrationFieldLabel">Service*</label>
    <span class="RegistrationFieldInput">
        <select id="serviceid" name="serviceid" class="RegistrationFieldBox"></select>
    </span>
    <span class="RegistrationFieldError">@Html.ValidationMessage("Service")</span>
</div>

<div id="regiontxt" class="RegistrationFieldLine">
    <label for="regionid" class="RegistrationFieldLabel">Region*</label>
    <span class="RegistrationFieldInput">
        <select id="regionid" name="regionid" class="RegistrationFieldBox"></select>
    </span>
    <span class="RegistrationFieldError">@Html.ValidationMessage("Region")</span>
</div>

<div id="regiontxt" class="RegistrationFieldLine">
  <label for="regionid" class="RegistrationFieldLabel">Region*</label>
  <span class="RegistrationFieldInput">
    <select id="regionid" name="regionid" class="RegistrationFieldBox"></select>
  </span>
  <span class="RegistrationFieldError">@Html.ValidationMessage("Region")</span>
</div>
    $("#serviceid").change('click', function () {
        //$('#regiontxt').show();
        //$('#regionid').show();
        getRegionByService($(this).val());
        document.getElementById('hservice').value = $(this).val();

    $("#regionid").change('click', function () {
        //$('#mtftxt').show();
        //$('#mtfid').show();
        getMTFByServiceRegion($(this).val(), document.getElementById('serviceid').value);
        document.getElementById('hregion').value = $(this).val();


    });

function getRegionByService(regionId) {
    var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
    var headers = {};
    headers['__RequestVerificationToken'] = token;
    var id = regionId;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: headers,
        url: "../Registration/UpdateRegionIds/",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "id": id }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#regionid').empty();
            $.each(data, function (i, data) {
                if (!data.RegionID == "") {
                    var div_data = "<option value='" + data.RegionID + "'>" + data.RegionName + "</option>";
                    $(div_data).appendTo('#regionid');

                }
            });
            document.getElementById('hregion').value = document.getElementById('regionid').options[0].value;
            getMTFByServiceRegion(document.getElementById('regionid').options[0].value, regionId);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            //alert(data.RegionID);
        }
    });
}
```

From the Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
  [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public ActionResult Index([Bind(Exclude = "model")] MyUser model, FormCollection reg)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        userData = Session["userData"] as MyProject.Models.users.UserCred;
        filter = new filteredRoles();
        filter.checkRoles(model);

        if (model.locations.Single() == "")
            ModelState.AddModelError("locations", "Please select one or more location's");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                result = RegisterUser(model, reg);

                if (result != "success")
                {
                    ViewBag.Result = result;
                    return View("Error");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.result = "Success";

                    ViewBag.first = model.Firstname;
                    ViewBag.last = model.Lastname;
                    ViewBag.email = model.Email;
                    ViewBag.phone = model.Phone;
                    ViewBag.expiration = model.ExpirationDate;
                }           
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.result = "Error";

                MyUser appusr = new MyUser();
                ViewBag.RegionId = new SelectList(appusr.regionList(), "RegionID", "RegionName", regiong);
                ViewBag.ServiceId = new SelectList(appusr.serviceList(), "locationServiceID", "locationServiceName", serviceg);
                ViewBag.RoleId = new SelectList(appusr.roleList(), "ABACUSUserRoleID", "UserRole", model.Roles);

                List<String> locationlist = new List<String>();

                    string[] yu = locationg.Split(',');
                    if (yu != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var x in yu)
                        {
                            locationlist.Add(x);
                        }
                    }

                ViewBag.locationId = new MultiSelectList(appusr.locationList(), "locationSiteID", "locationSiteName", locationlist);
                return View("Index", model);

            }
        return View("RegistrationResult", model);
    }
```

Comment: where is the HTML for `serviceid`?

Comment: Your code looks fine. What might be happening is some(or one) of the options in the `<select id="serviceid">` does not have a `value` or it is corrupt

Comment: Here is the HTML for serviced: oops. Newbie error. I added it to the code in the question.

Comment: you should display it in the question itself by editing it. Therefore, if I cannot help, somebody else may be able to

Comment: Right, but how are the `select` elements filled? Like I said in a previous comment, I would bet on the problem being in one/some of the `option` values

Comment: I assume you use `ViewBag.ServiceId` to fill the options. Now, are you able to verify that `ViewBag.ServiceId = new SelectList(appusr.serviceList(), "locationServiceID", "locationServiceName", serviceg);` is returning legit values %100 of the time? If there  are any nulls/empty/weird character values? That can throw off the binding in the controller and default the value to null

Comment: Yes, it is returning legit values. We scoured the database and found no bad data. We determined that it must be browser configuration. I'll add more info to the question.